# What function gets called when an iPhone app loads again after termination?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been trying to figure out which function gets called when your app terminates, and then loads up again. From my understanding, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions only gets called the first load, and after any updates.
Which one gets called when you load for a second, third time after termination?

**I cannot test with print statements because when you terminate in the simulator, nothing prints to the console anymore**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow()
    print("App Launched for the first time")
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("Will Resign Active")
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("Did Become Active")
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("App Entered Background")
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("App Entered Foreground")
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("App Terminated")
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle) help? What do you mean by "terminate"? Do you mean going back to the homescreen? Or shutting the app down completely using the multitasking screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` only gets called the first load, and after any updates.

Then your understanding is wrong. It is called every time the app launches.

> Which one gets called when you load for a second, third time after termination?

That would be `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

However, let's distinguish exactly what "load" means. I've been talking about what happens when the app launches, from scratch. But it is also possible that the app will just go into the background (so the user can use another app) and then come back to the front. In that case, the app does not "load"; it was never "unloaded", so it just picks up where it left off. In that case, you'll get `applicationDidBecomeActive` — except for an iOS 13 native app, where the corresponding event is sent to the *scene delegate*.

However, your question title says that the app "loads" *after termination*. In that case, yes, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("App Entered Background")
}
```

Above will call When you Close app even from stack, After that below will call

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("App Terminated")
}
```

And this will be call when u pressed home button or goes homeScreen

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("Will Resign Active")
}
```